# Not work Xdebug across a proxy server in docker

Tags: docker, xdebug, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have such a system deployed in my local environment. There is a docker container in which nginx is installed (used as a proxy server), which redirects requests to other docker containers on which Apache is installed. I want to install the Xdebug debugger on Apache containers and use it accordingly.
When asked, I see the error in the logs:

`Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal: 9005 (through xdebug.client_host / xdebug.client_port) :-(`

In the Dockerfile of the Apache container, I wrote:

```
RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && echo "xdebug.mode = debug" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.client_host = host.docker.internal" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
```

I wrote in docker-compose.yml:

```
  backend:
    build: backend
    container_name: backend
    volumes:
      # Re-use local composer cache via host-volume
      - ~ / .composer-docker / cache: /root/.composer/cache: delegated
      # Mount source-code for development
      - ./:/app
    expose:
      - 80
      - 9005
    depends_on:
      - console
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST = backend.cliq.com

  nginx-proxy:
    build: docker / nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    expose:
      - 9005
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
```

I assume that my xdebug connection does not reach the local machine through the proxy server, but I do not know how to fix it. Who has thoughts?

Comment: Why `expose: - 9005`? What for? remember: it's Xdebug that makes connections, it's Xdebug that connects to debug client (VSCode/PhpStorm/NetBeans/etc) and NOT other way around. If you expose that port then your IDE cannot listen it...

Answer (score 1):

Question was resolved. I add in docker-compose.yml

extra_hosts:
- "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"